# AngularJS User Login to Json file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I am currently trying to create a user login page where the user information is stored on a **json** file. I have created my **GET** method to the file but I cannot seem to redirect after the user has logged in successfully. Can you help me out?

> I know that user login and validation done on the client side is **A BAD IDEA** but that is how I want to do it, without using a database.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form id="login-form">
            <h3>User Login</h3>
                   <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                    </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="login-button" ng-click="LogOn()">Login</button>
        </form>
</body>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [ ]);
                app.controller("myCtrl",['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
                $scope.LogOn = function(){
                    $http.get('data.json').then(function(data){
                    $scope.users = data;
                    });
     if (data.email == email) && (data.password = password{
            window.location.href = 'www.google.com';
          }             
                    };  
                }]);
```

My JSON File:

```
[
    {
        "email":"something@yahoo.com",
        "Password":"password"
    },
    {
        "email":"test@yahoo.com",
        "password":"test999"
    },
    {
        "email":"xxx@mail.xx",
        "password":"xxx"
    }
]
```

Comment: You might want to look into ngRoute or ui.router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to open the link  and check and run the code which is deployed in w3 schools 
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDVZY3NXVYG6

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the `if` bellow has to be inside the `.then(` callback

```
if (data.email == email && data.password == password) {
   window.location.href = 'www.google.com';
}
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment - `if (data.email == email) && (data.password = password)`

Comment: Yes but checking the code if it runs in the first place is a vital part of giving an actual working answer. Thanks for your effort tho'

Answer (score 0):

Put redirection code inside then

```
$http.get('data.json').then(function(data){
          $scope.users = data;
          if (data.email == email && data.password == password) {
            window.location.href = 'www.google.com';
          }   
});
```

Comment: You're comparing an array of data against two strings.  You'll need to loop the users and match every user and password if you want to be able to enter your if stack.