# AngularJS Login using HTTP Get with a JSON file

Tags: angularjs, json, authentication, http-get

I am trying to create a user logon page where the user's input is compared against a JSON file of usernames and passwords (yes, I know client-side authentication is a *terrible* idea, but this is purely for developing my skills and isn't a real project.

```
$http.get('https://XXXXXXXXXX/user_list.json')
.then(function(response) {
  $scope.userlist = response.data;
  angular.forEach($scope.userlist, function(item) {});
});

$scope.JSONLogin = function() {
angular.forEach($scope.userlist, function(item) {
  if ((item.LoginName == $scope.uName) && (item.Password == $scope.pWord)) {
    window.alert("Success); //
  }

});
  }
```

I've been looking at this page [AngularJS User Login to Json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42953832/angularjs-user-login-to-json-file) for some guidance, but I can't seem to get something working. What am I missing?

Comment: Share a plunkr of whatever you have done and we can check what error you are facing